# Colspan works with some combinations but not others

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a table where both rows are three cells. I want the first row to be 3 equal width cells, while the second row has 2 equal width cells (each 1/4 of the first row's cells) and a third cell that fills up the rest of the row.

[Here is a picture of what I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abvG0.png)

I want to merge 3+4 in the top table, but when I actually merge them I get the second table.
Here is a fiddle that I have:
http://jsfiddle.net/9n3oyf2w/

```
<!-- This works: -->

<tr>
  <td colspan="4">a</td>
  <td colspan="2">b</td>
  <td colspan="2">c</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="1">1</td>
  <td colspan="1">2</td>
  <td colspan="1">3</td>
  <td colspan="5">4</td>
</tr>

<!-- This doesn't work: -->

<tr>
  <td colspan="4">a</td>
  <td colspan="2">b</td>
  <td colspan="2">c</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="1">1</td>
  <td colspan="1">2</td>
  <td colspan="6">3+4</td>
</tr>
```

I have no clue what I am doing wrong but it has been driving me crazy. I've tried other combinations of colspans and some of them work while others don't.

EDIT:

New pic for what I am trying to achieve:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ithN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want something like this?

```css
table, th, td{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border:0;
  border-spacing:0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

table.topInnerTable, table.topInnerTable td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

table.bottomInnerTable, table.bottomInnerTable td{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table width="960px">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="topInnerTable" width="100%">
        <colgroup>
          <col width="320px">
          <col width="320px">
          <col width="320px">
        </colgroup>
       <tr>
         <td>4</td>
         <td>4</td>
         <td>4</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="bottomInnerTable">
       <tr>
         <td width="80px">1</td>
         <td width="80px">1</td>
         <td width="800px">10</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not exactly, I just edited my post with a new picture of what I'm trying to get.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect that new image.

Comment: hmm, when I run the code snippet the 1's are almost half the width of the 4's each, and the 10 is the length of both 4's. This is the problem I've been having. It works with some colspans but not others.

Comment: What browser(s) are you using?

Comment: I've edited it again to nest 2 tables together.  That should be consistent across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want

```
<table width="100%">
   <tr>
       <td colspan="3" width="33%">a</td>
       <td width="33%">b</td>
       <td width="33%">c</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td width="10%">1</td>
       <td width="10%">2</td>
       <td colspan="3" width="80%">3+4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```